# Quick Reply Ajax Not Work Mybb

Tags: jquery, ajax, prototypejs, mybb

Like the title, my quick reply ajax is not working anymore. It's always loading!

I thinks it's not about jQuery and Prototype conflict, because I'm using **jQuery.noConflict()** and **jQuery** instead **$** everywhere.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what the problem is - maybe post some examples of what is not working so we can help you?

Comment: It's look like loading forever when I'm trying to post a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to revert `postbit_classic` template to default, after that implement your customisation.

**BUT**, you have to make sure that you have this code in your template:

```
<a name="pid{$post['pid']}" id="pid{$post['pid']}"></a>
<div style="{$post_visibility}" id="post_{$post['pid']}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have jQuery "every where", instead, the syntax should look like this;

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    // your jquery code
}
);
```